# Did Krishna and Rama ever sin, lie, or say falsehoods during their time on Earth?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, rama, sin

Did Krishna and Rama ever sin or lie while they were on Earth? Or were they morally infallible?

Also, did they ever say falsehoods?

Comment: Ramo Vigrahavaan Dharmaha;
KrishNam dharmam SanAtanam
says Ramayana and Mahabharata respectively.

Comment: Rama is the personification of Dharma;
One who has understood the quintessence of Vedas, knows supreme personality, Krishna  is the eternal Dharma .

Comment: @Athrey Does that mean they never sinned while in their human bodies?

Comment: Avatara(Rama,Krishna) , despite their appearance in human body , have neither any desire to attain anything   nor do they have an attachment in this material world .They transcend all human wants and needs. So there is no reason to sin. Their only purpose is to counteract  evil  and establish dharma, to sustain the grand order of manifestation.

Comment: @Athrey Where is this stated?

Comment: Bhagavad Gita 4.6, 4.7(Theory of Avatar) - Lord controls/subdues the Prakrithi ( nature) and assumes an embodiment, by His divine power,(atma Maya) unlike an ordinary birth of creatures that are determined by their forces of nature, thus are constantly in the sway of natural impulses .Lord is free from this  sway , so is not subjected by karma

Comment: Honestly depends on criterea of 'sin'. Some people say Vali's killing was sin but in Valmiki Ramayan, it is established that question of duel was never there because Shri Ram was there to punish not for battle.

Comment: As both are incarnations of the Lord, it is impossible for them to state a falsehood. This world of reality is dependent on God, what God says bends to his Will. It is therefore impossible for them to say any falsehood, as whatever they say becomes reality, past, present, or future.